# Let A,B,C be not null vectors such that...

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Good day guys, i'm starting with linear algebra but i got this problem that to be honest i don't know where to start:

> *"Let $A,B,C$ be not null vectors such that the angle formed by $A$ and $C$ equals to the angle formed by $B$ and $C$, then the vector $C$ is orthogonal to the vector $||B||A - ||A||B$."*

I would appreciate so much if you guys could help me with this proof.
Thank you.

Comment: Dot product${}$?

Comment: The norm $||A||$ was likely defined as square root $\sqrt{A\cdot A}$ of the dot product of $A$ with itself, but if you are "starting with linear algebra" it might be the case that you were working in a particular vector space like $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$ familiar from high school algebra.  Giving more information about the *context* of your problem helps Readers to respond in a more concise and useful way.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the scalar product, the angle between $A$ and $C$ and between $B$ and $C$ being equal means that 
$$\langle A, C \rangle / ||A|| = \langle B, C\rangle / ||B||.$$
Using this, compute
$$\langle ||B||A - ||A||B , C \rangle = ||B||\langle A, C \rangle - ||A||\langle B, C\rangle = 0.$$